# "ImportError: No module named pygame.base" - Pypy3 and pygame

Tags: python, debian, pygame, libraries, pypy

After several trials for install pygame in pypy3, I did it with the bitbucket version, cloning with mercurial and installing this way:

```
"pypypath"/bin/pypy3 setup.py
```

However, when I'll make the import, the following error appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rafael/PycharmProjects/pygame-teste/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "/opt/pypy3-2.4.0-linux64/site-packages/pygame/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: No module named pygame.base
```

This error also happened in python3 with Debian Wheezy, but worked when I was using pycharm.

Now, I'm using Debian Jessie and it imports pygame successfully in python3 from prompt, but pypy has this error now. (And don't import in pycharm too).

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pygame does not work on pypy. You can try pygame-cffi, but I'm not sure it's python 3 compatible. You might also need to improve places, since it's unfinished, but generally works.

Comment: but how i install it?
There is no a setup.py on pygame_cffi, so i just moved the folder to pypy site-packages folder, but its not importing pygame

Answer (score 0):

Pygame 1.9.2 supports Python 3.2 and up. Only the orphaned _movie module (not built by default) does not.

Python 3 can support Pygame; ANOTHER ANSWER IS NEEDED!